# Confused about queues, and how to implement them

Tags: c++, class, object, random, queue

I've been sort of stuck on this assignment of creating a bank queue.  Everything seems to be working fine up until I need to implement the queue part, I just don't think I know how to work it exactly, even after having done some research.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <CMATH>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

#define MAXCUSTOMERS 21

class account
{
private:
    string name;
    int ID;
    float balance;

public:



    string getname(string fn)
    {
        name = fn;
        return name;
    }
    int getID(int)
    {
        ID = rand() % 9000 + 1000;
        return ID;
    }
    int getbalance(int)
    {
        balance = rand() % 10000 + 1800;
        return balance;
    }
    float deposit()
    {
        int amount;
        cout << "Enter amount to be deposited: ";
        cin >> amount;
        balance += amount;
        cout << " Your balance currently stands at: " << balance << endl;
    }
    float withdraw()
    {
        int amount;
        cout << "Enter amount to be withdrawn: ";
        cin >> amount;
        if (balance <= amount)
            cout << "\nInsufficient balance! Operation Cannot be performed!" << endl << endl;
        else
            balance = balance - amount;
            cout << " Your balance currently stands at: " << balance << endl;;
    }
    void closeacc()
    {
        //not quite sure how to approch at the moment
    }
    void createacc()
    {
        // not quite sure how to approach at the moment 
    }
    void printinfo()
    {
        cout << " Name      : " << name << endl;
        cout << " Balance   : " << balance << endl;
        cout << " ID        : " <<  ID << " \n " << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    queue<account> accounts;
    vector<account> myvector;
    unsigned int money =0;
    unsigned int id=0;
    int numofacc;
    string name;
    numofacc = rand() % 11 + 10;

    cout << "There are currently : " << numofacc << " people waiting in line." << endl;

    account *a1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= numofacc; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter your name: " << endl;
        cin >> name;
        a1 = new account;
        a1->getname(name);
        a1->getbalance(money);
        a1->getID(id);  
        myvector.push_back(*a1);
        accounts.emplace(i);
    }
    vector<account> ::iterator it;
    for (it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end(); ++it)
    {
        it->printinfo();
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= numofacc; i++)
    {
        int input;
        accounts.front(i);

        cout << "Please tell me what you would like to do with your account:  \n"
            "Press 1 to Widthdraw money. \n "
            "Press 2 to deposit money . \n"
            "Press 3 to close the account. \n"
            "Press 4 to create a new account. \n" <<endl;
        cin >> input;

        switch (input)
        {
        case 1:
            a1->withdraw();
            accounts.pop();
            break;
        case 2:
            a1->deposit();
            accounts.pop();
            break;
        case 3:
            a1->closeacc();
            accounts.pop();
            break;
        case 4:
            a1->createacc();
            accounts.pop();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "You did not select 1 of the 4 options, you shouldn't be playing with money if you can't understand the basics of chosing a number." << endl;
            accounts.pop();
            break;
        }



    }




}
```

The error im recieving is where I try to get the front of the queue with this

accounts.front(i);

Not sure why this error us popping up.

Comment: Which error do you get ?

Comment: There are a bunch of other issues you need to consider too.  You're using numofacc in main before you initialize it with a value

Comment: _"I just don't think I know how to work it exactly, even after having done some research."_ This is not a scientific problem statement that we can address.

Comment: Why not read [some documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/front) before using a library? Oh I know, because you can dump your code here and someone will fix it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue)'s member called [`front`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) doesn't take any argument

so change

```
accounts.front(i);
```

to

```
a1 = &(accounts.front());
```

The second correction is in your `main()` function, the line where you wrote `accounts.emplace(i);`.. I presume you meant `accounts.emplace(*a1);`

And lastly, You have some member functions in your `account` class that are supposed to return something, but you failed to return anything.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm still trying to fully understand and implement pointers into my code so that may be the reason I missed those.  As for the member functions, I realized I'm better off just putting them as a void, since they cout what I need them to.

Comment: Ok, I am glad I helped. BTW, if I've solved your problem as regards to this question, you may approve this answer :-)

Comment: Why is it that when I try to delete the account (resetting ID and balance to 0) that it doesn't show up when I reprint the client information at the end?  I use this member function to do it, but it doesn't actually change the values 

  {cout << "You have successfully close the account " << endl;
   balance = 0;
   ID = 0;
   cout << " ----------------------- " << endl;
   }

Comment: @Ploxzx I can't really help you without seeing your code, try to upload the code snippet to any online code sharing and share the link in your comment

Answer (score 0):

Here're some questionable codes.

Discrepancy of the types of data between the class account and int:

queue accounts;
accounts.emplace(i);

queue::front argument:

accounts.front(i);

Answer (score -1):

I have tried you run your code , with my IDE Visual Studio community 2015 and I have received a few errors, at line 32, you are converting from int to float, which may cause data loss, same thing at the next line (33).
And what are you trying to do with `accounts.front(i);` ? The front function does not work like this.
[Front function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/front/)